# DataBindings.Add with an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, data-binding, datasource, report

I'd like to add a new dataBinding to a control in a report.

Usually I add a `IEnumerable<someObject>` to my bindings:

```
this.MyControl.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.CustomerDataSource, "Name");
```

But now I'd like to use an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
this.MyControl.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.MyStringDatasource, "?");
```

What would be the dataMember in this case? (I'm using a XtraReport from devExpress)

Comment: Does your datasource use the same object type? It's all an IEnumerable under the hood, so you should be able to use the same property name.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a two-parameter overload for this?

Comment: There is not a two-parameter overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me if that simply won't work; however, you can use a trivial projection, such as:

```
 var bindThis = sequence.Select(
     s => new { Value = s });
```

Then the member name is `"Value"`

Comment: Thank you for your help, the 100% correct answer is: DataSource = StringIEnumerable.Select(s => new { Value = s }).ToList(); Please edit you post to get the answer.

Comment: @Jean if the tolist is the important part there, it would have been better to express the original question in terms of a list, too :)

Answer (score 1):

If there's no two-parameter overload available, you can always use LINQ:

```
var ds = from str in this.MyStringDatasource
         select new { data = str };

this.MyControl.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "data");
```

Answer (score 1):

null worked for me...

```
BindingList<string> folderCollection = new BindingList<string>();

bindingSource1.DataSource = folderCollection;

textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to bind a control to an Ienumerable I do not believe the dataMember property is actually required at all. If you must set it, try setting it to null as I do not believe it is applicable in your situation.

Comment: I've tried to set the DataMember to null but I had an error "Value cannot be null".

Comment: Out of curiousity, What type of control are you attempting to work with here if I may ask?